# How to get rid of a random "%3" added to the beginning of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to write a jQuery function so that I can switch to a different page that has the same stuff on it but is in a different language. The code below is what using to actually change the page but as you can see in the picture below it, when I run it there is a "%3" added to the front of the URL string. Any ideas as to why this is?

```
$(langchooser).change(function() {
    var new_lang = $(langchooser).val();
    changeLanguage(new_lang);
    var x = location.host;
    var y = "/";
    var z = x.concat(y, new_lang);
    console.log(z);
    window.open(z, "_self");
});
```

[image: issue pic]

Comment: what value is there with `location.host` ? Did you print it?

Comment: Are you using jQuery?

Comment: note that that is not a valid url in any case; `location.host` is missing the protocol/scheme (`http://`)

Comment: Thanks Antti Haapala I added http:// to the front and it now works. :)

Comment: @AdamPohl Don't hard code it, use `location.protocol`

Comment: You can concatenate with the following too: `var a = b + c`.  If `b` is `"foo"`, and `c` is `"bar"`, `a` will be `"foobar"`

Comment: @AdamPohl see my answer

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`%31` is `1` encoded as the hex escapes.

The real problem is that your URL is missing the `http://` from the beginning; Chrome just has a bug in its error logging, where it URL-escapes the first character incorrectly.

Perhaps you should do

```
var l = window.location,
    url = l.protocol + '//' + l.host + '/' + new_lang;
window.open(url, '_self');
```

Comment: Should there not be an extra `1` then? `%31` and `127.0.0.1` ?

Comment: @dckuehn if you look at screenshot it is `%3127`; it is that the first `1` is encoded as `%31`.

Comment: @Antii Haapala Thanks.  I was expecting `%31127` because I assumed the `1` was being returned from the error logging, and that was being concatenated to `127`.  Not sure why I assumed that.